# How to get a each value by using array with java script?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to get a each value from a array, when I select or check each only I want to get a value. But there are some error, and I have no idea how to fix it.
What do I fix it to work well this? Please let me know. Thanks

```js
var pzArray = [];

function pizzaOrder() {
  var orderList = {
    pizzaName:"",
    size:"",
    topping:""
  };

  orderList.pizzaName = document.getElementById("pzName").value;
  orderList.size = document.getElementByName("pzSize").value;
  orderList.topping = document.getElementById("topping").checked;

  pzArray.push(orderList);

  for (var i = 0; i<pzArray.length; i++) {
    var pizza = pzArray[i];
    invoice = pizza.size + pizza.pizzaName + pizza.topping;
    totalInvoice += invoice + "<br>"
  }
  document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = totalInvoice;
}
```

```html
   <body>

<div>

    <input type=radio id="pzName" name=pzSelect value="A">a
    <input type=radio id="pzName" name=pzSelect value="B">b
    <input type=radio id="pzName" name=pzSelect value="C">c

    <br><br>

    <select>
        <option name="pzSize" id="small" value="Small">S
        <option name="pzSize" id="medium" value="Medium">M
        <option name="pzSize" id="large" value="Large">L
    </select>

    <br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="ExtraCheese" value="Extra Cheese">XtraC
    <input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="Pepperoni" value="Pepperoni">P
    <input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="Mushrooms" value="Mushrooms">M

    <br><br>

    <input type=button value="Order Description" onClick="pizzaOrder()" />

</div>

<span id="showlist"><span></span>


</body>
```

Comment: Please define "_some error_".

Comment: i<pzArray.length in for loop

Comment: @Teemu I edited my code, you can know the error of this code. Thanks.

Comment: @Supercool. Thanks. I just missed it. But that was not a big problem.

Comment: @Teemu. Yep, that was just my mistake. But there are another problem.

Comment: Please describe your problem. What you want your code to do, and what it does instead? SO is not a Quiz Game where we're guessing what people want their code to do.

Comment: @Teemu. I got this error "message": "ReferenceError: pizzaName is not defined", And I just want to fix this code in order to work be well.

Comment: Take a look at the code where you're defining `orderList`, do you think the syntax is correct? You've defined an object like an array, objects are key-value pairs, not lists of values.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you for letting know me about the problem. I understand the cause as a theroy but I have no idea how to change the code to put each value into array. Thus I ask to help you guys.

Comment: Push orderList not prderList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were couple of errors not setting name in string you were setting `name=pizSelect` instead of `name="pizSelect"` ,typing mistakes in ids , not initializing the `totalInvoice` with var or let and missing condition in forloop  `i<pzArray.length`.

As for radio buttons you can do `document.querySelector("input[name=pzSelect]:checked").value`
to get the value

```js
var pzArray = [];
function pizzaOrder() {
 document.getElementById("showlist").innerHTML
  var orderList = {
    pizzaName:"",
    size:"",
    topping:""
  };
  orderList.pizzaName = document.querySelector("input[name=pzSelect]:checked").value;
  orderList.size = document.getElementById("psize").value;
  let toppings=document.querySelectorAll("input[name=topping]:checked");
  toppings.forEach( (topping)=> orderList.topping+=topping.value+"," ) ;
  let totalInvoice="";
  pzArray.push(orderList);
  for (let i = 0; i< pzArray.length; i++) {
    let pizza = pzArray[i];
    invoice = `Order number : ${i+1} ${pizza.size} ${pizza.pizzaName} with ${pizza.topping}`;
    totalInvoice += invoice + "<br>"
  }
  document.getElementById("showlist").innerHTML = totalInvoice;
}
```

```html
<h4>Order Pizza</h4>
<div>
    <!-- in your code you have not included pzSelect in " " -->
    <input type=radio id="pzName" name="pzSelect" value="Chicago">Chicago Pizza
    <input type=radio id="pzName" name="pzSelect" value="Sicilian">Sicilian Pizza
    <input type=radio id="pzName" name="pzSelect" value="Detroit">Detroit
Pizza    <br><br>
    Size
    <select id="psize">
        <option name="pzSize" id="small" value="Small">Small
        <option name="pzSize" id="medium" value="Medium">Medium
        <option name="pzSize" id="large" value="Large">Large
    </select>

    <br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="topping" value="Extra Cheese">XtraC
    <input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="topping" value="Pepperoni">Pepporni
    <input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="topping" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms

    <br><br>

    <input type=button value="Order Description" onClick="pizzaOrder()" />

</div>

<span id="showlist"><span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your orderList object properly. Either first as an empty object:

```
var orderList = {};
// then adding the attributes
orderList.pizzaName = document.getElementById("pzName").value;
orderList.size = document.getElementByName("pzSize").value;
orderList.topping = document.getElementById("topping").checked;
```

or by directly initializing the objects attributes

```
var orderList = {
    pizzaName = document.getElementById("pzName").value,
    size = document.getElementByName("pzSize").value,
    topping = document.getElementById("topping").checked
}
```